# React - importing stateless component causing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import a stateless component into my app and am getting the following error:

> App.jsx:13 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/test"

and

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/test'

Here is my code:

**App.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Username from './components/test';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello React :)</h1>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**test.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const Username = function(props) {
  return (
    <p>The logged in user is: </p>
  )
}
export default Username;
```

can't understand why it's giving this error?

Comment: what happens if you try `import Username from './components/test.jsx'`

Comment: THat was it Emil! I'm using a new boilerplate so was just used to importing without the .jsx. Any ideas where I can fix this? I take it it's a babel thing?

Comment: It looks like the path is incorrect, please verify that the path is relative './components/test' to App.js

Comment: @BenLiger It's a webpack thing. You need to add `.jsx` to `resolve.extensions`: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: if you want to answer the question then ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to import `jsx` files without specifying an extension you need to modify your webpack config slightly.

You need to add `.jsx` to the `resolve.extensions` array (it defaults to `[".js", ".json"]` so you should set it to `[".js", ".json", ".jsx"]` and make sure that `resolve.enforceExtension` is set to `false` (which is the default.)